# no wifi adapter found, Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Dell Latiude with Intel wireless adapter

Tags: networking, wireless, dell, 22.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on my Dell Latitude 7240. After some days using it (and a few software updates) the wireless network is no longer working. I get the "No wi-fi adapter found" message.

Kernel version is `Linux 5.15.0-46-generic x86_64`

with `sudo lshw -C network` I get

```
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 73
       serial: 0c:8b:fd:27:8f:fd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-46-generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:50 memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
```

throwing `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` I get

```
[    3.611949] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.851701] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    3.875699] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 0c:8b:fd:27:8f:fd
[    4.140485] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    4.563907] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

I tried several other answers to this same issue but non worked. (Or, at least I wasn't able to...)

Any help highly appreciated!

Update: `throwing rfkill` list I get:

```
2: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
3: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: yes
  Hard blocked: no
4: phy0: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
5: nfc0: NFC
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
```

Output starts with number 2. (don't know if it's correct).

Tried entering `sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 up` but nothing happens.

Comment: Try moving the small wireless switch on the left side near the cooling port

Comment: thanks. I forgot to mention I  already did. As a matter of fact, Bluetooth (which is also powered on/off via the same switch) is turned on.

Comment: What does `rfkill list` show?

Comment: I added the output in the question, so it's neatly formatted

Comment: Try `sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 up`

Comment: I did it. Nothing happens :-(

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/425180/300665 and post wireless script results

Comment: thank you so much. it's here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Pt8WWZr9m4/

Comment: Uninstall the Broadcom driver, then reboot

Comment: I believe that `/etc/network/interfaces` is incorrect and should be restored to defaults.

Comment: I shall propose an answer that I hope you will accept: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file `/etc/network/interfaces`, as shown in your paste, suggests that the mostly deprecated ifupdown mechanism will control your wireless interface. In fact, you are expecting Network Manager to control. That is, you want to click on the NM icon, see your network and connect.

Please use any text editor to revert the file to its defaults. Afterwards, reboot. You should be all set.